# conditional haml - if else nesting

Tags: ruby, haml

What I want is both whats in "if" and whats in "else" to include #main-block.

```
- if @transparency
  #content-inner{:style => "background: url(../../../images/illustrations/" + @transparency + ") no-repeat 88% 50%"}
- else 
  #content-inner
     #main-block
```

What happens currently is, if `@transparency` is defined, `#main-block` is not nested inside `#content-inner`.

Comment: looks like same post as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451794/haml-if-else-error - though they didnt seem to get an answer other than duplicate

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to conditionally apply the style attribute:

```
#content-inner{ :style => @transparency ? "background: url(../../../images/illustrations/" + @transparency + ") no-repeat 88% 50%" : '' }
  #main-block
```

For a more complicated arrangement, for example manipulating multiple hash attributes, it's best to either use a helper method, or to move the common content to a partial.

Comment: Just saw your answer and wanted to add that if you had to evaluate Ruby inside of that conditional, you could do as I've done: `.request{ :class => (request.user_id == current_user.id) ? "highlight" : nil }`.  In the case of how I have to render this (long story), I couldn't make an instance variable, thus I evaluate the Ruby in parentheses to see if this request object `belongs_to` the `current_user` and if it does, I add the `highlight` class to the div. Just figured I'd share this tidbit if someone else didn't already figure it out.