# Need help on a specific example of conversion of erb to haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Since haml doesn't use `end` to end an if/else control flow, how would I convert the following erb to haml?

```
<% if klasstype == :klasses %>
  <div id="instructor_table">
<% else %>
  <div id="ta_table">
<% end %>
  <div id="table">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also how accurate are converters like html2haml? I tried to use the converter on this code and it didn't seemed to work.

Thanks!

Comment: What issue did you run into using html2haml?  The coveter is pretty sound since, as long as your encapsulations are strictly hierarchical (i.e. you don't start a tag inside say a `div` and then end it outside that `div`) you shouldn't be having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ternary to fit the conditional into one line:

```
%div{ :id => (klasstype == :klasses) ? "instructor_table" : "ta_table" }
  #table
```

See also: [conditional haml - if else nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742041/conditional-haml-if-else-nesting)